# Google cloud vision api-OCR , C#,Deadline Exceeded Exception

Tags: c#, exception, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to use google cloud vision OCR API to read text from image.

```
using System;
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;
namespace blablabla
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = @"D:\Manisha\Pictures\1.png";
            var image = Image.FromFile(filePath);
            var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
            var response = client.DetectText(image);
            foreach (var annotation in response)
            {
                if (annotation.Description != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(annotation.Description);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

var response = client.DetectText(image); This lines gives exception : Status(StatusCode=DeadlineExceeded, Detail="Deadline Exceeded")

Comment: As I said in your previous question, you follow the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started - download a service account JSON file and set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to refer to it. The code should then work fine. The `Google.Cloud.Vision.V1` library does *not* work with API keys.

Comment: I AM GETTING THIS ERROR. 
Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.'

Comment: Right, that suggests that you haven't set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to refer to the file - at least, not in the environment you're running it in. If you've set it in a command prompt, that will only affect *that* command window. If you've set it for your user with the Windows control panel tool, then you'll need to restart any command shells *and* I suspect you'll need to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Yeah i set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and restarted my visual studio. Client gets created. Thanks

Comment: var response = client.DetectText(image); 

This lines gives exception : Status(StatusCode=DeadlineExceeded, Detail="Deadline Exceeded")

Comment: Right, so either you've set a short deadline, or the default deadline is too short for the image you're analyzing. The current V1 API doesn't support doing this using long-running operations, but you could use the Google.Cloud.Vision.V1P1Beta2 API if you wanted to try that... is your image particularly large? At this point it may be worth editing this question with the details so it's no longer about authentication, but is instead about this deadline issue.